# Adding .class files in NetBeans 8.0.2

Tags: java

I've been assigned to add `.class` files into a current project for using their instance methods in other classes.

However, `cannot find symbol` error, remains when I try to initialize an object or use the `.class` methods in my current project.

So far, I tried creating a new Java library, uploaded the `.class` files, extracted the  `.jar` file after clean & build, to no avail. (made sure the `.class` files weren't located in a default package!)

Thank you for helping out!

**Edit**

[code-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDg5e.png)

Comment: Just put the jar on your classpath.

Comment: I just checked, the .jar path is under libraries > compile tab.

Comment: Then that's all you need to do. If your jar is on the path, the objects are available for use in your current projects as long as you import them from the correct packages used in the jar.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I had just tried importing the `.class` files - still cannot use those classes (added a screenshot) Thank you for you help!